# Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled

Tags: tensorflow2.0, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

While running kubeflow pipeline having code that uses tensorflow 2.0. below error is displayed at end of each epoch

> W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled

Also, after some epochs, it does not show log and shows this error

> This step is in Failed state with this message: The node was low on resource: memory. Container main was using 100213872Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container wait was using 25056Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

Comment: I'm getting the first error as well. Haven't seen the second error yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to incompatible CUDA and Tensorflow versions.
below versions work well with each other

> tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
>
> tensorflow-addons==0.6.0
>
> nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-runtime

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I didn't match the `batch_size` and `steps_per_epoch`

For example,

```
his = Test_model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(trainrancrop_images, trainrancrop_labels, batch_size=batchsize),
                               steps_per_epoch=len(trainrancrop_images)/batchsize,
                               validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
                               epochs=1,
                               callbacks=[callback])
```

`batch_size` in the datagen.flow must correspond to the `steps_per_epoch` in Test_model.fit_generator
(actually, I used the wrong value on the `steps_per_epoch`)

This is one of the cases for the Error, I guess.

**As a result, I think the problem arises when there is wrong correspondence on the batch size and steps(iterations)**

Maybe the floats can be a problem when you get the step by dividing...

Check your code about this issue.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading `tensorflow` from `2.1` to `2.2` fixed this issue for me. I didn't have to go to `tf-nightly` version.

Comment: Upgraded TensorFlow  2.1 to TensorFlow 2.2 and this issue is gone. me

Comment: @user3284804 - Please consider upvoting if this answer helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I am running tensorflow-gpu on a conda env and it keeps installing version 2.1 and if I try to upgrade it using pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu i can't use it no more 
does anyone know how to upgrade a tensorflow-gpu version inside of a env

Comment: @Dhouibiiheb What do you mean by you cannot use it anymore?

Comment: @Safwan meaning that when I try the following : pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.2 / 2.3 tensorflow won't work anymore.. as far as I know, conda env supports tf 2.1 for now, not sure though

Comment: @Dhouibiiheb `conda` supports tf2.2 now. Use `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` to install tf2.2

Comment: @Safwan I tried it already, nothing changes won't update tf to tf2.2

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. People claimed that warming is superfluous and it has been removed in the tf-nightly, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35100). But the memory leak is still there for each epoch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I installed tf-nightly.
Now it's working, Though I am new to tensorflow. I followed this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%20Error%20occurred%20when%20finalizing%20GeneratorDataset%20iterator%3A%20Cancelled%3A%20Operation%20was%20cancelled)

You can try.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you can add `workers=1` in `model.fit(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following steps and it worked in my case

```
conda install tensorflow=2.0.0
conda install -c conda-forge keras=2.3.0
```